# How to efficiently extract list index if its element satisfy in between condition in Python

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, conditional-statements

The objective is to extract list index if its element reside in between two references values.

The code below answer the objective.

```
l=[0,61,83,99]

range_set=[(first, second) for first, second in zip ( l, l [1:] )]
range_el = range ( 6, 100, 6 )
all_set=[]
for x,y in range_set:
    val=[idx for idx, element in enumerate ( range_el ) if x <= element  and element <= y]
    all_set.append(val)
```

But I wonder whether there is more compact and efficient way of achieving the same. Recommendation using `Numpy` is welcome

Comment: Are you collecting `idx` or `element` in `val`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
arr = np.arange ( 6, 100, 6 )
```

and

```
val=np.nonzero(x<arr)&(arr<y))[0]
```

in place of your inner comprehension.